# What's an example of a best linear predictor that's not a best predictor?

Tags: forecasting, predictor

I just learned about the definition of a best linear predictor found by minimization of variance of 
$Y$ given $X$, or in other words trying to minimize the variance of 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\{Y-\hat{Y}(X)\}^{2}\right) \,\,.$$ This is found to be: 
\begin{equation*} \operatorname{Pred}(X_{n+h}|X_{n}, \text{...}, X_{1}) := \mu + (a_{1}, \text{...}, a_{n})^{T}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{n} - \mu \\
\vdots\\
X_{2}-\mu \\
X_{1} - \mu
\end{pmatrix} \,\,,
\end{equation*}

where $\mathbf{a}$ satisfies the equation:
$$\Gamma{(\mathbf{a})} = \gamma_{(n,h)} := (\gamma(h), \text{...}, \gamma(h+n-1))^{T} \,,$$
where $\Gamma$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $ij^{\text{th}}$ element $\Gamma_{ij} = \gamma(|i-j|)$.

I immediately recognized that a best linear predictor would not imply being the best predictor. That being said, I'm having a hard time coming up with an actual *situation* where that would be the case, or moreover conceptualizing qualities which would make best linear predictors insufficient.

Comment: That looks *linear*, but nothing there seems to suggest that you have the *best* one unless you specify some things about $\mathbf{a}$. What's the criterion for *best* here? minimum variance unbiased? MMSE? something else?

Comment: @Glen_b $\mathbf{a}$ satisfies the auto-covariance equation, yeah.

Comment: Could you address that issue (including what the autocovariance equation is) in the question, and then address the remaining issues please? (also in your question)

Comment: @Glen_b Does that address your concerns?

Comment: Yes, thanks. You can minimize variance by setting all your predictions to 7. Or $\sqrt{\pi}$. Either would work, since both have variance 0. Once you sort that detail out, note that If the $X$'s are not Gaussian, linear predictions won't in general be minimum variance.

Comment: @Glen_b Mind pointing out what's missing with my definition?

Comment: Nothing -- if you don't mind biased estimates (assuming it's not me that missed something).

Comment: @Glen_b I have been exhausting what I know. I know that I write the predictor as a function of $X_{1}, \text{...}, X_{n}$. I then know I differentiate with respect to my term $a_{0}$ and find that when covariance is nonsingular the best linear predictor is given by what I have provided. I know that the autocovariance function must be satisfied. I do _not_ know what it is that is missing from my understanding of the definition that is allowing biased estimates, or simply plugging in a constant. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on how I could rectify the definition, and perhaps

Comment: @Glen_b why having non-Gaussian terms in the process will pose a problem to linear predictions.

Comment: The issue isn't with your definition of the linear predictor, it's with what other estimators it's allowed to compete with -- the definition of the cirterion "best" simply as *minimum variance* admits predictors with variance 0 that ignore the data. As to why non-Gaussian variables will generally have lower-variance predictors that are nonlinear functions of the past data. that would be an issue for an answer to address; first we need to clarify this "best" criterion so that it does more than simply specify "minimum variance"

Comment: @Glen_b How does my _best_ criterion look now?

Comment: When you write $E\left(\{Y-\hat{Y}(X)\}^{2}\right)$ isn't that what you're seeking to minimize, rather than its variance (you say "minimize the variance of $E\left(\{Y-\hat{Y}(X)\}^{2}\right)$" ... are you sure?). Note that if you do minimize $E\left(\{Y-\hat{Y}(X)\}^{2}\right)$ you're actually minimizing *mean square prediction error* (what I was originally trying to get at when I mentioned MMSE, but should have perhaps been more explicit about it being MMSPE).  Note that this change in criterion may also change the relevance of some of my earlier comments.

Comment: @Glen_b Ah, yes that is what I meant. That terminology isn't used in my courseware, rather just "best linear predictor".

Comment: Are the examples given [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html) useful, see in particular 21. and 23.?